# How to apply animation on onClick event in React

Tags: reactjs, ionicons

I want to create add to favorites button with [IonIcons](https://zamarrowski.github.io/react-ionicons/) library. I put the `icon name` and the `animation state` in the React state.

Then I want to change those with `onClick` function. But for some reason animation doesn't work. It is nothing special, just true or false.

The state is correct. If I console log it:

- Before click : `{icon: "md-heart-outline", iconAnimation: false}`
- After click: `{icon: "md-heart", iconAnimation: true}`

But the animation **isn't** applied. The icon changes and that is fine but the animation doesn't work.

My code is as follows:

State:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {             
            icon: "md-heart-outline",
            iconAnimation: false
        }
    }
```

In render function I have an `IonIcon` component as follows:

```
render(){
    return (
        <Ionicon
             icon={this.state.icon}
             fontSize="30px"
             color="red"
             beat={this.state.iconAnimation}
             onClick={this.handleFavorites.bind(this, vehicle, favorites)}
             style={{cursor: "pointer"}}
        />
    )
}
```

And function `handleFavorites` is as follows:

```
handleFavorites(vehicle, favorites, event){
    this.setState({icon: "md-heart", iconAnimation: true});
}
```

Comment: try once passing the `beat` attribute like this: `beat={this.state.iconAnimation ? true : false}`

Comment: @Syed No. the same problem.

Comment: Just verify whether its working or not, if we pass the `beat` attribute directly as `beat={true}`

Comment: @Syed It works. If I in initial state set `iconAnimation: true` it works too.

Comment: i tried your code in codesandbox. its working fine. check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/zr239yxrnp

Comment: @Syed I see it. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work.